# Differential to Single-Ended Converter + Common-mode Shift + Sallen-Key Filter (Is one Stage Possible?)

Tags: differential, active-filter, single-ended

I have a differential signal that needs to be conditioned as follows:

1. Convert from differential to single-ended.
2. Filter with a 3rd order Sallen-Key filter
3. Common-mode shift into an single-ended, single-supply ADC.

Of course three separate stages can be cascaded to produce the desired effect. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to combine all three into a single stage?

Any ideas on whether this is even possible would be helpful!

Comment: Sallen & Key's paper discusses 1st order and 2nd order active filters (and passives.) Higher order are broken down. So #2 would require two stages, if Sallen-Key. Also, Sallen-Key isn't differential. It's single-ended. Perhaps if you'd show how you'd do all this with three stages, it may help us have better insight into your question.

Comment: There are 3rd order Sallen-Key filters in a single stage, or at least Sallen-Key "alike", you can do the filter and common-mode shift with a single opamp, you would need another opamp for the differential to single ended conversion, which is no problem if you consider that many opamps come in a dual configuration, 2 per package, so physically its mostly the same to use 2 opamps or 1 opamp, in both cases its only one chip.

Comment: Hi S.s., I'm not familiar with how a Sallen-Key can also perform the common-mode shift. Could you point me in the right direction, maybe with a picture or a link. Feel free to provide this as an answer, as this may be sufficiently close to my original question to close this question out. Thank you!